# Show list in listview in full

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, android-listview

I have a listview inside ConstraintLayout which must show all my list im full, and make constraintlayout bigger. All options what i found dont work in my case.

All this options which i tried not showing listview completely, every option leaves a half or more items to scroll

Here is my xml :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/question_content_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

                ...

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/answers_list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question_tv"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                ...

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

           ...

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I already tried :

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {
        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();
        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, 0);
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);
        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

and

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        int itemCount = listAdapter.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount; i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED );
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (itemCount - 1)));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the only solution what i found it is to swap ListView with RecylerView;

Answer (score 2):

What has worked for me to have a listview and be able to scroll through it is to have the scrollview as the parent view, and have the constraint layout inside of the scrollview.

Comment: I have like max 10 items, with only one textview. So its not like big deal for perfomance i think. ListView is enough

Comment: Damn.. i found out that it still not working.. if listview shows in full and goes out from screen then scollview comes locked, and i cant scroll it, and sometimes when listview way more bigger than it should be for fit inside screen listview dont shows in full.

Comment: I just swap listview with recyclerview and it has started to work perfectly. Magic...